# Why did the command uniq -c put a whitespace at the beginning?

Tags: command-line, uniq

I have this code in a shell script:

```
sort input | uniq -c | sort -nr > output
```

The input file had no preceding white spaces, but the output does. How do I fix this? This is in bash

Answer (score 16):

> The default behavior of **uniq** is to right-justify the frequency in a
> line 7 spaces wide, then separate the frequency from the item with a
> single space.

Source : [https://www.thelinuxrain.com/articles/tweaking-uniq-c](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104041001/https://www.thelinuxrain.com/articles/tweaking-uniq-c) (Wayback Machine)

Remove the leading spaces with sed :

```
$ sort input | uniq -c | sort -nr | sed 's/^\s*//' > output
```

Comment: 7 spaces, aka "just less than a tab".

Comment: You can then separate with tabs with something like `perl -pe 's/ *(\d+) /$1\t/'` ([here some alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11670393/4970442)). Also pipe to clipboard with `xclip -selection c` to paste directly to a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 7):

`uniq -c` adds leading whitespace. E.g.

```
$ echo test
test
$ echo test | uniq -c
      1 test
```

You could add a command at the end of the pipeline to remove it. E.g.

```
$ echo test | uniq -c | sed 's/^\s*//'
1 test
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW you can use a different sorting tool for more flexibility. Python is one such tool.

### Source

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys, operator, collections

counter = collections.Counter(map(operator.methodcaller('rstrip', '\n'), sys.stdin))
for item, count in counter.most_common():
    print(count, item)
```

In theory this would even be faster than the `sort` tool for large inputs since the above program uses a hash table to identify duplicate lines instead of a sorted list. (Alas it places lines of identical count in an arbitrary instead of a natural order; this can be amended and still be faster than two `sort` invocations.)

### Output Format

If you want more flexibility on the output format you can look into the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) and [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) built-in functions.

For instance, if you want to print the count number in octal with up to 7 leading zeros and followed by a tab instead of a space character with a NUL line terminator, replace the last line with:

```python
    print(format(count, '08o'), item, sep='\t', end='\0')
```

### Usage

Store the script in a file, say `sort_count.py`, and invoke it with Python:

```sh
python3 sort_count.py < input
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uniq -c -i | tr -s ' ' | cut -c 2-
```

Translate leading whitespaces into single whitespace with tr -s and then print output from 2nd character with cut -c.

Comment: Your solution will squeeze all occurences of whitespace sequance. This is is the desired effect.